# wkhtmmltopdf has been deprecated

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I want to download `wkhtmltoPDF` to convert HTML to PDF using C# from [here](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-installer.exe&can=2&q).

But when I click the following message appears:

> This file has been deprecated. Another file would probably be better. Do you want to continue?

What does that mean? Where can I download a better wkhtmltoPDF exe?

Answer (score 0):

When using google to look for the library, you find the official site.
Which has the [downloads page](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) where you can download a newer version.

Comment: but where can I download the wktmltoPDF.Can you share me the exact link

Comment: I linked you to the page which lists the downloads. Seriously, what more do you want.

Comment: Is wkhtmltoPDF is free for all commericial products?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know that library. All I did was spend 5 seconds on google. Perhaps you should try the same.